# Customer booking API - Create bookingCustomer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When creating a new bookingCustomer object the displayName property value is replaced by emailAddress value:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/Contosolunchdelivery@M365B489948.onmicrosoft.com/customers
Content-type: application/json
{
    "displayName": "Joni Sherman",
    "emailAddress": "jonis@relecloud.com"
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-type: application/json

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#bookingBusinesses('Contosolunchdelivery%40M365B489948.onmicrosoft.com')/customers/$entity",
    "id": "36038f36-634e-44e4-9415-d7d59c2347aa",
    "displayName": "jonis@relecloud.com",
    "emailAddress": "jonis@relecloud.com"
}
```

The example from docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-post-customers?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http):

Same story over HTTP and SDK.

Any toughts?

Comment: What is exactly the question here? Why is it overriden?

Comment: Still can you repro the issue or issue is fixed?